# What is the difference between _mm_movehdup_ps and _mm_shuffle_ps in this case?

Tags: x86, sse, intrinsics, micro-optimization, sse3

If my understanding is correct,

`_mm_movehdup_ps(a)`

gives the same result as

`_mm_shuffle_ps(a, a, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 3, 3))`?

Is there a performance difference the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`_MM_SHUFFLE` takes the high element first, so `_MM_SHUFFLE(3,3, 1,1)` would do the [`movshdup`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movshdup) shuffle.

The main difference is at the assembly level; `movshdup` is a copy-and-shuffle, avoiding a `movaps` to copy the input if the input `a` is still needed later  (e.g. as part of a horizontal sum: see [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86) for an example of how it compiles without a `movaps` vs. the SSE1 version that uses `shufps`.

`movshdup`/`movsldup` can also be a load+shuffle with a memory source operand.  (`shufps` obviously can't, because it needs the same input twice.)  On modern Intel CPUs (Sandybridge-family), **`movshdup xmm0, [rdi]` decodes to a pure load uop, not micro-fused with an ALU uop**.  So it doesn't compete for ALU shuffle throughput (port 5) against other shuffles.  The load ports contain logic to do broadcast loads (including `movddup` 64-bit broadcast), and `movs[lh]dup` duplication of pairs of elements.  More complicated load+shuffle like `vpermilps xmm0, [rdi], 0x12` or `pshufd xmm, [rdi], 0x12` do still decode to multiple uops, possibly micro-fused into a load+ALU depending on the uarch.

---

Both instructions are the same length: `movshdup` avoids the immediate byte, but `shufps` is an SSE1 instruction so it only has a 2-byte opcode, 1 byte shorter than SSE2 and SSE3 instructions.  **But with AVX enabled, `vmovshdup` does save a byte**, because the opcode-size advantage goes away.

---

**On older CPUs with only 64-bit shuffle units (like Pentium-M and first-gen Core 2 (Merom)), there was a larger performance advantage**.  `movshdup` only shuffles within 64-bit halves of the vector.  On Core 2 Merom, `movshdup xmm, xmm` decodes to 1 uop, but `shufps xmm, xmm, i` decodes to 3 uops.  (See https://agner.org/optimize/ for instruction tables and microarch guide).  See also my horizontal sum answer (linked earlier) for more about SlowShuffle CPUs like Merom and K8.

---

#### In C++ with intrinsics

If SSE3 is enabled, it's a missed optimization if your compiler doesn't optimize `_mm_shuffle_ps(a, a, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 1, 1))` into the same assembly it would make for `_mm_movehdup_ps(a)`.

Some compilers (like MSVC) don't typically optimize intriniscs, though, so it's up to the programmer to understand the asm implications of avoiding `movaps` instructions by using intrinsics for copy-and-shuffle instructions (like `pshufd` and `movshdup`) instead of shuffles that necessarily destroy their destination register (like `shufps`, and like `psrldq` byte-shifts.)

Also MSVC doesn't let you enable compiler use of SSE3, you only get instructions beyond the baseline SSE2 (or no SIMD) if you use intrinsics for them.  Or if you enable AVX, that would allow the compiler to use SSE4.2 and earlier as well, but it still chooses not to optimize.  So again, up to the human programmer to find optimizations.  ICC is similar.  Sometimes this can be a good thing if you know *exactly* what you're doing and are checking the compiler's asm output, because sometimes gcc or clang's optimizations can pessimize your code.

Probably a good idea to compile with clang and see if it uses the same instructions as the intrinsics in your source; it has by far the best shuffle optimizer out of any of the 4 major compilers that support Intel intrinsics, basically optimizing your intrinsics code the same way compilers normally optimize pure C, i.e. just following the as-if rule to produce the same result.

The most trivial example:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m128 shuf1(__m128 a) {
    return _mm_shuffle_ps(a,a, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,3, 1,1));
}
```

[**compiled with gcc/clang/MSVC/ICC on Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwngC2OhQWIKAdAg3YOABgCCV6wH17O2lwAcqwQhEAzWhEfObqpMAJTqAOx8NqoxqsSYBGIsqk469p4%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%2BXFTBhTYMVFQlNVpTlBUlxVNUNQtFkdT1RUDSNE0zSwf9rR%2BS1RkYEVHV4fgXUpN0IA9L08B9f0uS4YN6WQJBrAANQADVUAB6ABxGU0zEDMeg%2BKYATzaQn1LHRBDPVRryre9a3rIhiC7Fs21xTs5FkMJlnI3h%2BwFQdh1HMkJxnb4p3%2BRcFhXIQ1w3Q5SBOacMNkHNAWBEzN23ALkT3HTMSPYKTxQe1gFcP4XxJMkKS/Jcfz/IiAL0DluV5fklyFEUoNyvBJTg%2BVASQ9VNTS9D9UNY1GVw1C9iMQjdjtUjOCMgQsOo2jvV9aQAyDEMwz9SNo1jViEyTEhMFTIR00kMSMIk%2BzlykAsixLVQlBFVRXGMSwDtU/B1M01twoxJsuAM3s/Nc8yxys9z/gw2d5zsnzHLBCEBy3REgv3MlD2xC7LLwCsbyJeKPypGk6UZf82UykCcsFcD8otQritlUrFXKlD/2qzDapw818Oa20SIdDq%2BGdbr4F6%2Bj%2BqkQbg1DCMoxjP04zYjQhgQJhBAAd11BhhI2TNxO8qT1sLYtS3BoMbwO6tjobDS5Hoc7AY17YHhuzq7rMkdHpo6y51sySl18pyftMycPOkLyrYckF1wHSc3mMe9ZAeC5XloCYuCubYuA%2BOafloWLVptlzBwwuaY8cuOxjlckmZAB4gA%3D%3D)

GCC and clang with `-O3 -march=core2` both spot the optimization:

```
shuf1:
        movshdup        xmm0, xmm0
        ret
```

ICC `-O3 -march=haswell` and MSVC `-O2 -arch:AVX -Gv` (to enable the vectorcall calling convention, instead of passing SIMD vectors by reference.)

```
shuf1:
        vshufps   xmm0, xmm0, xmm0, 245                         #4.12
        ret                                                     #4.12
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. I almost answered that the two approaches should be the same, but I should have known that you would come in to prove me wrong! I also wasn't aware that ICC was hesitant to optimize intrinsic use further, that is potentially a big deal in more complicated cases.

Comment: @JasonR: I'm not sure if ICC/MSVC simply don't know how, or if that's *intentional* so using intrinsics is more like really writing asm.  GCC (and clang with the right options) will also contract mul + add into FMA, but I haven't looked at MSVC and ICC recently.  I'm not sure MSVC even has an option to enable FMA, unless they tie that into `-arch:AVX2` (even though those are separate feature bits, and there are AMD CPUs with FMA3 but not AVX2, and there's unfortunately even a Via CPU with AVX2 but *not* FMA3).